# OAuth2 request failed: Invalid credentials after password change (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am developing a Chrome extension. I am getting an oAuth token with below code which works fine, however after changing my gmail password and enabling 2 factor authentication on my account today I am getting: Unchecked runtime.lastError while running identity.getAuthToken: OAuth2 request failed: Invalid credentials.

How can I force a redirect to repeat the authorization process instead?

Here is my background.js

```
var access_token;
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
    {        'interactive': true},
    function(token) {access_token = token;
        console.log (access_token);
        // Authorized
    }
);
```

Comment: The problem continues, I somehow initiated a fresh start and got a new token. After signing in and out of gmail and switching Chrome users I am now stuck again with an empty token, revoking doesn't work, I get the error:  Service responded with error: 'Invalid Credentials'. Renewing also doesn't work and returns the same error.  On chrome://identity-internals I see a NULL valued token, but I can not delete it.